# How does node.js handle authentication/user systems?

Tags: javascript, python, authentication, node.js

I come from Django's framework, and it has built in "user" system.  It takes care of all the registrations, passwords, logins, etc.

Does Node.js  have this?

Comment: This is a very strange comparison. Django and node are two very different tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to browse through the packages on the [**node package manager (npm) registry**](http://search.npmjs.org/) for NodeJS extension modules that can be combined to enable you to authenticate users, talk to external user management systems, etc. For example, the [**node-http-digest extension**](https://github.com/thedjinn/node-http-digest) for HTTP digest authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed the documentation and found no user management system.

node.js is a JavaScript server where-as django is an MVC with built-in socket utilities.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at [connect](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/) and [express](http://expressjs.com/) node.js modules. Namely express (which is built on top of connect) can be "compared" with Django's funcionality.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but wanted to share this link in hopes it can help others who come across this question.

Checkout Drywall; A website and users system for Node.js

http://jedireza.github.io/drywall/